# Getting an "undeclared character encoding" error in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, character-encoding

I'm working through the [JS SPA book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1617290750) and noticed I get different results in chrome vs firefox. Here is the code...

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>SPA Chapter 1 section 1.2.2</title>
  <style type="text/css"></style>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var prison = function () {
      console.log('made it to prison');
    };
    prison();
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="spa"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Nice and simple...no? In chrome I get the expected result of "made it to prison" in the console. However, in FF only get an error that reads...

```
The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol.
```

What gives? Is there a setting I'm missing in the FF webdev console?

Comment: Try adding the tag `<meta charset="utf-8">`. I don't think this has anything to with the `console.log`.

Comment: Are you sure the console was already open when you reloaded the page?

Comment: How are you serving the page? Does the page show normally (maybe add some content)?

Comment: @pstenstrm That gets ride of the endcoding error, but I still do not get the console display in FF...still works fine in chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox shows the expected result in the console log, when you enable console logging in dev tools. It also shows a message, classified as an error message in some versions but not affecting the functionality. It is effectively an informational message that says that the character encoding of the page was not declared in any way; see the [W3C page on encodings](http://www.w3.org/International/O-charset).

The way to control what is shown in the console log depends on the dev tools you are using. Using the [built-in dev tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools) in the current version of Firefox, called Aurora, which you can invoke with <kbd>Ctrl Shift K</kbd>, make sure that “Logging” is enabled (appears in black, not grey) as in this image:

[image]

You need to decide on the character encoding. For any modern application, there is seldom need to consider any other option than UTF-8. You can declare it by saving the HTML file as “UTF-8 with BOM” in your text editor and/or by using the tag `<meta charset=utf-8>` in the `head` part. If you only use the latter and if the page is ever sent via HTTP, you should make sure that the server does not send conflicting information in the `Content-Type` HTTP header.

Comment: Where is this 'All' tag you speak of?

Comment: @Lumbee, this is somewhat confusing, since people use different dev tools. I changed the answer to use a more generic wording and to illustrate that with a modern example.

Comment: That did it..logging was turned off...not sure how that happened. Thanx!